# ionic2 - ion-content to the top of the screen

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic2

I am developing a mobile app that deal with a lot of images. My client want the app main page to have a full screen background image edge to edge. But all I can achieve so far is like the image below:
[image: ion-content gap]

I just not sure how to get rid of the white gap on top. Here are my code:

**home.html**:

```
<!--<ion-header>   <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      Ionic Blank
    </ion-title>   </ion-navbar> </ion-header>-->

<ion-content>   <div class="gmHomeTopScreen">
    <p *ngIf="user">
      <i>Welcome, {{user}}</i>
    <p>
    <button class="button button-clear button-positive"  (click)="openModal({charNum: 0})">
      Gollum
    </button>   </div> </ion-content>
```

**home.scss**:

```
page-home {

.gmHomeTopScreen{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;   
 background-color: #999;
}
}
```

I read the [`ionicframework` docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/content/Content/) about `content`, they did have a instance member called `contentTop`. But I am not sure how to use it.

2. How is it possible for me to set every page with the `ion-content` on top of the page? I know it has to do with `app.scss` but I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: possible to add a `margin-top: -15px !important` or `padding-top: 0 !important;` to your custom class

Comment: Strange. I did not do anything and the white space disappear. I have no idea how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `fullscreen` attribute to `ion-content`